# How to combine 2 index.html,both of different directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models = Generator and Results. Generator has_many : results and Result belongs_to:generator.

Views/generator/index  and view/results/index have their own data. What i want to do is to have those 2 index page merge as 1. How should i do that ? Please show some examples if could. I'm new to RoR ...

Comment: I think you want to show generators and their respective results on one page. In that case, you'll want to modify the generator view to include results using something like `generator.results`

Comment: yes that's what i want to do. How should i do it ? I did try generator.results.ncbi_ref_seq but the errors pops out saying undefined method results

Comment: what's `ncbi_ref_seq`?  And is there some Generator object in generator or not. Why don't you use pastebin or gist to provide a few pieces of code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is some kind of home page or dashboard for your app.
For such cases I typically create a separate controller not to mess in my other RESTful ones.

To render two other views you may do

```
<%= render template: "generators/index" %>
<%= render template: "results/index" %>
```

Just remember to set all required variables (probably `@generators` & `@results`) in controller action

Comment: Hi michael , so i need 2 create a new controller ? because now i've got Genrator controller n Result controller .   Lets say after i created the new controller , what should i do with that ? where should i place those 2 render templte code in ? and how should i call those collections. for example @generator.primer_length ( primer length is  1 of the attributes of generator)

Comment: I mean - if you don't understand how to use my answer you REALLY should get and LEARN Rails not just try writing code with no understanding how it works.